# Error on creating SpringBoot SOAP Web Service using XSD

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I have been following this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

I completed successfully the sample project they have with the countries example, but when I tried to use my XSD schema, it will create the WSDL, but when I test it using SOAP UI, I get the following error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public com.p44.domain.DispatchResponseType worldwide.DispatchEndpoint.getDispatch(com.p44.domain.DispatchRequestType)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSD schema:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="DispatchRequest" type="DispatchRequestType"/>

  <xs:element name="DispatchResponse" type="DispatchResponseType"/>

  <xs:element name="RateQuoteResponse" type="rateQuoteResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="RateQuotes" type="rateQuoteResponseList"/>

  <xs:element name="RateRequest" type="RateRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="TrackingResponse" type="trackingResponseList"/>

  <xs:element name="TrackingResult" type="TrackingResultType"/>

  <xs:element name="change" type="mergeRecord"/>

  <xs:element name="error" type="serviceError"/>

  <xs:element name="rateDetail" type="rateDetail"/>

  <xs:complexType name="trackingResponseList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="errors" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="shipmentInfo" type="TrackingResultType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="serviceError">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="errorMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendorErrorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendorErrorMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TrackingResultType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="lastUpdated" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="actualDeliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="appointmentDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="appointmentDateEnd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="billTo" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bolNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="carrierNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="carrierScac" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipmentId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipper" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="consignee" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="consigneeAccount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="currentStatus" type="trackingStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="originTerminal" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="destinationTerminal" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="disclaimer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="errors" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="estimatedDeliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="invoiceStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="items" type="trackingItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="nextTerminal" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="notifyContact" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="numPieces" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="otherBOLNums" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="otherPONums" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="parentPro" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="paymentTerms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupDateTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="poNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="proNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="receivedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="receivedByDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipmentExceptions" type="exceptionStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="shipperAccount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="statusHistory" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="status" type="trackingStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="totalQuantity" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="totalWeight" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="trailerNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="images" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="imageRecord" type="imageRecord" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="changeLog" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="change" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="addressInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="address1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="address2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="address3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="contactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stateName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="postalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="phoneNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="phoneNumber2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="faxNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="trackingStatus">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stateName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="interlineScac" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="notes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceCenter" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="timestamp" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="updateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="terminalInfo">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="addressInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="terminalId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="terminalName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="terminalNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="terminalCarrier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="trackingItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="descriptionCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="freightClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pieces" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="rate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="exceptionStatus">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="trackingStatus">
        <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="imageRecord">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="imageType" type="imageType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="imageFormat" type="imageFormat" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="imageLink" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="mergeRecord">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="RateRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="shipDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipTimeStart" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipTimeEnd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="returnMultiple" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="loginGroupKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="delTimeStart" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="delTimeEnd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="destination" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="origin" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="billTo" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="accountNumbers">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="accountConfigs" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="account" type="accountConfigType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lineItems" type="rateQuoteLineImpl" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="accessorials" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="cubicFeet" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="defaultLogins" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="mapChargeCodes" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="requestedScacs" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="limitByScacs" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="rateQuoteLineImpl" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="accountConfigType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="vendorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="siteLoginName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="defaultAccount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="accountNumber2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="credentials" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="paymentTerms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="authKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="authKey2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shipmentTerms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="inboundPayTerms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="outboundPayTerms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="direction" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="paymentType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rateQuoteLineImpl">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nmfcItem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="nmfcSub" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="weightUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="freightClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="length" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="width" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="height" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="dimUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="palletCount" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="numPieces" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pieceType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="packageType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stackable" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="DispatchResponseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="errors" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bolLink" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="carrierBolLink" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="contactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="debtor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="origin" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="destination" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="dockCloseTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="labelLink" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lineItems" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="lineItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pickupDateTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="poNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="proNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bolNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteTotal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteVersion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="referenceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="scac" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="transitTime" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceTypeCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceTypeDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stopNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="terminalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="terminalPhone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="trackingNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="requestId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendorNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="barcodeNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="lineItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="hazmatId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shippingName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="hazmatClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="packagingGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="weightUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="freightClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="hazmat" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pieces" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="packageType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="length" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="width" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="height" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="density" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="nmfcItem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="nmfcSub" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stackable" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="DispatchRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="vendorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="accountConfig" type="accountConfigType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="accountNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="contractId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="loginGroupKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="emergencyContact" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="emergencyPhone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="referenceNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bolNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="proNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="scac" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bolPDFContent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="createBOL" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteTotal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="requestBOL" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="origin" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="destination" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lineItems" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" type="lineItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pickupNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="dockCloseTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="billTo" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="requester" type="addressInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="poNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="bolContactPhone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupDateTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryDateTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupContactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupPhone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryContact" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryContactPhone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupEmail" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupContactCompany" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="accessorials" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="emailBOLShip" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailNotifyShip" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailApptShip" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailDelivShip" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailBOLCons" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailNotifyCons" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailApptCons" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailDelivCons" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="emailConfirm" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupStartTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pickupEndTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryStartTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryEndTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rateQuoteResponseList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="rateQuote" type="rateQuoteResponse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="loginGroupKey" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rateQuoteResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="scac" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="vendor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="contractId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="originTerminal" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="destinationTerminal" type="terminalInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="errors" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="carrierNote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="expirationDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="quoteDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element ref="rateDetail" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="totalPallets" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="totalPieces" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="totalWeight" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="transitTime" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="alternateRates" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="alternateRate" type="rateDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rateDetail">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="rateAdjustments" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="rateAdjustment" type="rateAdjustment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="total" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="subtotal" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="deliveryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="rateAdjustment">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="freightClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pieces" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="descriptionCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="rate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="imageType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="BOL"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="INVOICE"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="DR"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="WCERT"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="imageFormat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="PNG"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="TIF"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="PDF"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="JPG"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="GIF"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my endpoint class:

```
@Endpoint
public class DispatchEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://domain.p44.com";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "DispatchRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public DispatchResponseType getDispatch(@RequestPayload DispatchRequestType request) {
        //TODO: Some logic will be here...
        DispatchResponseType response = new DispatchResponseType();
        return response;
    }

}
```

I think I followed the right way, but I don't know why SOAP UI is showing such error. Please help me as I'm completely lost on what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I want to post the solution for those of you having the same problem.

```
@Endpoint
public class DispatchEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://domain.p44.com";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "DispatchRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<DispatchResponseType> getDispatch(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<DispatchRequestType> request) {
        //TODO: Some logic will be here...
        DispatchResponseType response = new DispatchResponseType();
        QName qname = new QName(NAMESPACE_URI, "DispatchResponse");
        return new JAXBElement<DispatchResponseType>(qname, DispatchResponseType.class, response);
    }

}
```

I wrapped the response and request in a JAXBElement object. This solved my problem.